# Function applied in loop on two different dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have two `dataframes`. The first (`games`) shows, for each of several games, the year and which player accomplished certain unspecified goals (`player1`, `player2`, `player3`). The second (`rankings`) show the ranking of each player in a given year.

My goal is to add a column to the `games` dataframe, indicating the average ranking of all players who accomplished those goals in each game.

A reproducible example:

```
set.seed(0)
players <- c("Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "John", "Jane", "Linda", "Mason", "Zoe", "NA")
years <- c(2000:2005)
season <- sample(years, 20, replace = TRUE)
player1 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player2 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player3 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
games <- data.frame(season, player1, player2, player3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rankings <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:5,8,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(rankings) <- years
ranked_players <- players[-9]
rankings <- cbind(ranked_players, rankings)
```

The `games` is the first `dataframe`, showing the year of the game (`season`), who was `player1`, who was `player2` and who was `player3`. There isn't always a player for all categories for all games.

The `rankings` is the second `dataframe`, showing the ranking from 1 to 5 of each player in a given year.

I want to calculate what is the ranking of the player who played as `player1`, `player2`, and `player3` respectively for each game in games, and average those rankings.

To calculate the ranking, I tried this function:

```
calc_ranking <- function(x, y) {
  z <- select(filter(rankings, ranked_players==x), c(y))
  z <- as.integer(z[1,1])
  z
}
```

It apparently works. Now I have to apply it for each player who played a game in games and for every year.

I tried this loop:

```
new_col <- mapply(calc_ranking, games$player1, games$season)
```

but it doesn't work. It gives me an error

```
 Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n
```

However, even if it worked, with this solution I should repeat the loop 3 times to create 3 columns, one for each role as `player1`, `player2`, and `player3`, and then create the column I really want (the average of the 3 columns). I suspect there is a more efficient way to do it without repeating the loop (assuming I can fix it)? It would be very useful, because in my real dataset I have 13 "roles" for which I have to calculate the ranking.

Hope this second question is better than my first. Apologize for any mistake, I'm only 1 week into learning R (which is my first experience with coding in general).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a quick comment I think you missed out on defining `season` when creating your reproducible data

Comment: thanks, hopefully now it's fixed

Comment: Can you also show your expected output for the given example?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that each row in `games` is a separate game id. So for:

```
season    player1    player2   player3
  2001        Joe       Bill      Jane

player    season     ranking
   Joe      2001           1
  Bill      2001           3
  Jane      2001           5
```

The intended answer is 3 for that one game. To address this, melting the data and then merging the two `data.frames` on the season and player name would be the simplest route. **Edit:** added output similar to @heds with the `dcast()` lines.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(games)
games[, game_id := seq_len(.N), keyby = season]

molten_games <- melt(games, id.vars = c('season', 'game_id'), variable.name = 'player_number', value.name = 'player')

setDT(rankings)
molten_rankings <- melt(rankings, id.vars = 'ranked_players', variable.name = 'season', value.name = 'ranking', variable.factor = F)[, season:= as.integer(season)]

merged_dt <- molten_rankings[molten_games
                             , on = .(season
                                      , ranked_players = player )
                             , nomatch = 0L
                             ]

merged_dt[, mean(ranking, na.rm = T), by = .(season, game_id)]
    season game_id       V1
 1:   2000       1 2.666667
 2:   2001       2 2.000000
 3:   2001       3 1.333333
 4:   2001       4 4.000000
 5:   2002       1 3.333333
...
#or if you want all the players and rankings
dcast(merged_dt, season + game_id ~ player_number, value.var = c('ranked_players', 'ranking')
      )[, means := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = c('ranking_player1', 'ranking_player2', 'ranking_player3')][]

    season game_id ranked_players_player1 ranked_players_player2 ranked_players_player3 ranking_player1 ranking_player2 ranking_player3    means
 1:   2000       1                   John                  Mason                    Zoe               2               2               4 2.666667
 2:   2001       1                   <NA>                    Zoe                   <NA>              NA               4              NA       NA
 3:   2001       2                  Chris                   Jane                  Linda               1               1               4 2.000000
 4:   2001       3                   Jane                   Jane                   John               1               1               2 1.333333
 5:   2001       4                  Linda                    Zoe                    Zoe               4               4               4 4.000000
...
```

Since it appears you use `dplyr`, this is a similar approach although I couldn't figure out the way to make it wide at the very end:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

long_rankings <- rankings%>%
  gather(key = 'season', value = 'ranking', - ranked_players)%>%
  mutate(season = as.integer(season))

long_games <- games%>%
  arrange(season)%>%
  group_by(season)%>%
  mutate(game_id = row_number())%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  gather(key = 'player_number', value = 'player', -season, - game_id)

inner_join(long_rankings
           ,long_games
           , by = c('season' = 'season'
                    , 'ranked_players' = 'player'))%>%
  group_by(season, game_id)%>%
  summarize(game_rank_ave = mean(ranking, na.rm = T))

   season game_id game_rank_ave
    <int>   <int>         <dbl>
 1   2000       1          2.67
 2   2001       1          4   
 3   2001       2          2   
 4   2001       3          1.33
 5   2001       4          4   
 6   2002       1          3.33
```

Regarding generating your data, please be careful about `cbind()`!! It coerces objects into a matrix and matrices can only have one class such as character or numeric. I addressed the data.frame generation to address the issue.

**Data used:**

```
set.seed(0)
players <- c("Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "John", "Jane", "Linda", "Mason", "Zoe", "NA")
years <- c(2000:2005)
season <- sample(years, 20, replace = TRUE)
player1 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player2 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player3 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
games <- data.frame(season, player1, player2, player3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rankings <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:5,8,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(rankings) <- years
ranked_players <- players[-9]
#rankings <- cbind(ranked_players, rankings) ##don't cbind unless you're making a matrix!
rankings$ranked_players <- players[-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted your desired output a bit differently than @Cole, being that you wanted the column of means of the player ranks per game. My strategy was to extract the players into their own dataframes (while having to change the column names to not be numeric). Then, for each of `player1`, `player2` and `player3`, look for the player in that "position", and look up their ranking from their individual dataframe. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but it worked in this case (although I'm not sure it's exactly what you're after.

**Output:**

```
> head(games,10)
     season player1 player2 player3 player1_rank player2_rank player3_rank    means
1  year2005   Mason    John    John            3            3            3 3.000000
2  year2001    <NA>     Zoe    <NA>           NA            4           NA       NA
3  year2002     Bob   Linda   Chris            3            4            3 3.333333
4  year2003   Linda     Zoe    Jane            5            5            3 4.333333
5  year2005     Bob    Jane   Chris            5            1            3 3.000000
6  year2001   Chris    Jane   Linda            1            1            4 2.000000
7  year2005    John     Zoe   Chris            3            3            3 3.000000
8  year2005     Abe     Abe    Jane            4            4            1 3.000000
9  year2003    John    Jane   Mason            1            3            3 2.333333
10 year2003     Zoe   Mason     Abe            5            3            5 4.333333
```

**Code:**

```
for (player in players){
    temp_player <- filter(rankings, ranked_players == player)
    colnames(temp_player) <- c("player","year2000","year2001","year2002","year2003","year2004","year2005")
    assign(paste(player), temp_player)
}

games$season <- paste0("year",games$season)
games[games=="NA"] <- NA

i <- 1
for (rows in games$player1){
        if (!is.na(games$player1[i])) {
            season <- games$season[i]
            games$player1_rank[i] <- get(games$player1[i])[,season]
        }
        else
        {
            games$player1_rank[i] <- NA
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }

i <- 1
for (rows in games$player2){
        if (!is.na(games$player2[i])) {
            season <- games$season[i]
            games$player2_rank[i] <- get(games$player2[i])[,season]
        }
        else
        {
            games$player2_rank[i] <- NA
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }

i <- 1
for (rows in games$player3){
        if (!is.na(games$player3[i])) {
            season <- games$season[i]
            games$player3_rank[i] <- get(games$player3[i])[,season]
        }
        else
        {
            games$player3_rank[i] <- NA
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }

games$means <- rowMeans(games[,5:7]
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(0)
players <- c("Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "John", "Jane", "Linda", "Mason", "Zoe", "NA")
years <- c(2000:2005)
season <- sample(years, 20, replace = TRUE)
player1 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player2 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
player3 <- sample(players, 20, replace = TRUE)
games <- data.frame(season, player1, player2, player3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rankings <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:5,8,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(rankings) <- years
ranked_players <- players[-9]
rankings <- cbind(ranked_players, rankings)
```